# php to highchart, how to send the right array?

Tags: php, json, highcharts, influxdb

I made this code with:

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-php

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

```
<?php 
include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/example/vendor/autoload.php');

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 8086;
$dbname = 'aTimeSeries';

/*
$client = new \InfluxDB\Client($host, $port);

$database = $client->selectDB('aTimeSeries');
*/

//the exact same thing
$database = \InfluxDB\Client::fromDSN(sprintf('influxdb://user:pass@%s:%s/%s', $host, $port, $dbname));

//query of the last value
$result = $database->query('select * from valeurs group by * order by desc limit 1');

//recup le point
$points = $result->getPoints();

// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: application/json");

// The x value is the current JavaScript time, which is the Unix time multiplied by 1000.
$x = time() * 1000;
// The y value is a random number
//$y = rand(0,100);
$y = $points;

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);

?>
```

**Output:**

`[1523603506000,[{"time":"2018-04-13T07:11:45.208943754Z","value":48}]]`

But I would like this:

```
[1523603506000,48]
```

Or this:

```
[2018-04-13T07:11:45.208943754Z,48]
```

If I try to output `$points` only, I got only the last part of the array, but it is not what I would like either.

PS: if you have a better solution to do the same thing, maybe with nodeJS, I will surely listen

Comment: What does your `getPoints()` do/return? Because I think that is returning the `[{"time":"2018-04-13T07:11:45.208943754Z","value":48}]]`

Comment: Yes, it is. And I would like to keep only the last value 48.

Comment: Can't you just access the `value` in the JSON? I'm not that good with php but it seems to me that there should be a way to call the value by the name. (`$points.value`  perhaps? Something in that way?)

Comment: This is what I'm trying to find, but I'm research have not been successful yet.

Comment: Perhaps `$test = json_decode($points)` `echo $test->value`  ? I'm assuming `getPoints()` returns a JSON

Comment: Close @Codeer, it's actually `echo $test[0]->value;` (there is a top-level array in the JSON)

Comment: So the solution is `$y = json_decode($points); $ret = array($x, $y[0]->value);`

Comment: I tried but : json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ...      $points is an array but when I tried echo implode(",", array_keys($points)); , It doesn't return the keys

Comment: Looks like I misinterpreted where the top-level array was. Try `$y = json_decode($points[0]); $ret = array($x, $y->value);`

Comment: OK, just find the solution, you're all good guys, $points = json_encode($points);
$points = json_decode($points); Weird but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help,
I had another problem, but I solved it.

But still have 2 hours of lag, but it display right in highcharts now.

```
<?php 
include('/opt/lampp/htdocs/example/vendor/autoload.php');

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 8086;
$dbname = 'aTimeSeries';

//directly get the database object
$database = \InfluxDB\Client::fromDSN(sprintf('influxdb://user:pass@%s:%s/%s', $host, $port, $dbname));

//query of the last value
$result = $database->query('select * from valeurs group by * order by desc limit 1');

//get the point
$points = $result->getPoints();

//make the array right
$points = json_encode($points);
$points = json_decode($points);

//take only the seconds of the time
$points[0]->time = substr($points[0]->time, 0,20);

// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

// The x value is the current JavaScript time, which is the Unix time multiplied by 1000 and take the time
$x = strtotime($points[0]->time) * 1000;

// The y value take the value which is a random value
$y = $points[0]->value;

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);

?>
```